# Вопрос про вывод описания и изображения дочерних рубрик

Tags: php, wordpress

На сайте есть рубрика "Книги". У которой две дочерние рубрики: "Отечественные книги", "Иностранные книги". Некоторые книги небольшие, так что публикуются как обычные записи, а некоторые большие, по несколько десятков глав. Для таких больших создаю еще дочерние рубрики. В общем, структура выглядит так:

- Главная страница

  - Книги (рубрика)

    - Отечественные книги (рубрика)

      - Книга 1 (рубрика)

        - Глава 1 (запись)
        - Глава 2 (запись) и т.д.
      - Книга 2 (запись)
      - Книга 3 (запись) и т.д.

Так вот, проблема в том, что если анонсы всех нескольких десятков глав Книги 1 будут выводиться в рубрики "Отечественные книги", "Книги" и на Главную страницу, то это займет очень много места в лентах рубрик (и эта Книга 1 не единственная такая), да и вообще бессмысленно.
Конечно, можно просто исключить их из показа в рубриках плагином Simply Exclude, но тогда они становятся не видны и в собственной рубрике "Книга 1".
Как указать, чтобы из конкретной рубрики (ID) выводились только ее описание и изображение (записи этой рубрики выводились только в родительской), а обычные записи выводились везде как всегда?

Код файла content.php такой:

```
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="svg-container post-svg svg-block">
        <?php echo oblique_svg_3(); ?>
    </div>  

    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ( get_theme_mod( 'index_feat_image' ) != 1 ) ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-thumb">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'oblique-entry-thumb' ); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="thumb-link-wrap">
                <span class="thumb-link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?> 

    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ( get_theme_mod( 'index_feat_image' ) != 1 ) ) : ?>
    <div class="post-inner">
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="post-inner no-thumb">
    <?php endif; ?>     
    <?php if ( strlen(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'creator', true)) > 0) {
    echo '<div class="creator2">'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'creator', true).'</div>'; 
}
?>
        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' ); ?>

            <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() && ! get_theme_mod( 'meta_index' ) ) : ?>
            <div class="entry-meta">
                <?php oblique_posted_on(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
            <?php endif; ?>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

            <?php
                wp_link_pages(
                    array(
                        'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'oblique' ),
                        'after'  => '</div>',
                    )
                );
            ?>
        </div>

        <!-- .entry-content -->
        <?php do_action( 'oblique_post_entry_content_bottom' ); ?>
    </div>
        <?php do_action( 'oblique_link_to_single' ); ?>

    <div class="svg-container post-bottom-svg svg-block">
        <?php
        do_action( 'oblique_post_bottom_svg' );
        ?>
    </div>  
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Добавил картинку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И где у вас выводятся эти главы? Какая-то функция? В коде я не нашел. В общем эту функцию надо подправить.

Comment: Этот код, выводящий имя автора (creator), заголовок (title) миниатюру изображения записи (thumbnail) и анонс (excerpt) записей в категориях по сайту. Надо как-то добавить, чтобы выводился анонс и дочерней категории (определенной), но не знаю, как это сделать, о чем и спрашиваю.

Comment: Нарисовать то что вы хотите  есть возможность? :)

Comment: Ок, добавил в сообщение картинку :)

Comment: А если для таких рубрик-записей, создавать просто новую запись с другим шаблоном. Т.е как вы написали скрываете эти рубрики от показа, создаете новую запись которая будет выводится в общем списке записей, указав нужное вам название и описание. В качестве шаблона указываете новосозданный вами шаблон, в котором вы будете получать рубрику этой записи, и выводить все подрубрики.

Comment: Я пока так и сделал: создал новый шаблон записи для этой книги с новым сайдбаром, где список глав книги. Сделал скрытыми для рубрик все записи (главы) книги, кроме одной, с обложкой книги и предисловием, которая и выводится в вышестоящие рубрики. Так, конечно, тоже можно. Но если в "хлебных крошках" нажать на название этой рубрики книги, то попадаешь на страничку, где одиноко обретается единственный анонс этой самой обложки с предисловием, а не все главы, как хотелось бы. И если наставить на записях метки, они бодро висят в облаке меток, но если нажать на какую-то из них, то... null.

Comment: В общем, задача нерешаемая, да? Поискал в плагинах, но подходящего не нашел...